# How to configure lambda trigger for Amazon S3 object upload multiple prefixes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda

I am trying to configure serverless.yml file for two prefixes in the same bucket for a lambda.

The code for a simple object upload trigger works fine:

```
events:
      - s3:
          bucket: ${self:custom.environment.env}-bucket-name
          event: s3:ObjectCreated:*
          rules:
            - prefix: folder/path1/
            - suffix: .csv
          existing: true
```

How can i configure it for two prefixes say - folder/path1/ and folder/path2/

Comment: What about just add more events?

Answer (score 0):

You use create them using the following way, also make sure they don't overlap

```
   events:
      - s3:
          bucket: ${self:custom.environment.env}-bucket-name
          event: s3:ObjectCreated:*
          rules:
            - Name: prefix
              Value: folder/path1/
            - Name: prefix
              Value: folder/path2/
            - Name: suffix
              Value: .csv
          existing: true
```

Comment: Nopes, doesn't work -> Received response status [FAILED] from custom resource. Message returned: filter rule name must be either prefix or suffix

Answer (score 0):

Solution -

The root cause of the error came to be prefix/suffix rule overlapping with another lambda function in the same environment.

Learning -
The prefix/suffix overlapping rule is applied globally through all the lambdas and not only on the single lambda function currently being configured.